Project for reading and printing IPs
It's a small project which consists of Ip class and functions for reading and printing IPs, unit tests for this code, and a driver app. The driver app is just reading a set of IPs delimited with newline from std::cin and prints them into std::cout. I would like to get a review of the project structure, CMake configs, unit tests, and code itself. Cmake configs and unit tests are important because I have little to no experience in both topics and are included for learning pupuse. The next step for this project may be adding code to filter IPs. Thanks in advance.
Here is a project structure:
- driver_app
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - main.cpp
- ip_lib
  - include
    - ip_lib
      - ip.h
  - src
    - ip.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
- tests
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - ip_stream_operators_test.cpp
  - test_ip_reading.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt

Contents - driver_app:
CMakeLists.txt:
add_executable(driver_app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(driver_app PUBLIC ip)

set_target_properties(driver_app PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")

# deb-package.
set(CPACK_GENERATOR DEB)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "driver_app")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "amd64")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "amd64")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deb")
include(CPack)

main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "ip_lib/ip.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto [ips, success] = ip::readIps(std::cin); 
    if(!success){
        std::cerr << "Some errors occured..." << std::endl;
    }
    for (const auto& ip : ips){
        std::cout << ip << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}

Contents - ip_lib:
ip.h:
#pragma once

#include <iosfwd>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <cinttypes>

namespace ip {

constexpr inline size_t partsCount = 4;
constexpr inline char   delimiter  = '.';

class Ip
{
public:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &input, const Ip &ip);
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, Ip &ip);

    Ip() = default;
    Ip(uint8_t p1, uint8_t p2, uint8_t p3, uint8_t p4);

    constexpr uint8_t       &operator[](size_t i) { return parts_[i]; }
    constexpr const uint8_t &operator[](size_t i) const { return parts_[i]; }
    bool           operator==(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ == rhs.parts_; }
    bool           operator!=(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ != rhs.parts_; }
    bool           operator<(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ < rhs.parts_; }
    bool           operator<=(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ <= rhs.parts_; }
    bool           operator>(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ > rhs.parts_; }
    bool           operator>=(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ >= rhs.parts_; }

    constexpr bool is(uint8_t p1, uint8_t p2, uint8_t p3, uint8_t p4) const { 
        return p1 == parts_[0] && p2 == parts_[1] && p3 == parts_[2] && p4 == parts_[3];
    }

private:
    std::array<uint8_t, partsCount> parts_ = {};
};

// Returns vector of read IPs and flag, that is true if reading performed without errors.
std::pair<std::vector<ip::Ip>, bool> readIps(std::istream& stream);

} // namespace ip

ip.cpp:
#include "ip.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

namespace ip {

Ip::Ip(uint8_t p1, uint8_t p2, uint8_t p3, uint8_t p4) : parts_ { p1, p2, p3, p4 }
{
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const ip::Ip &ip)
{
    output << static_cast<uint16_t>(ip.parts_[0]);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < partsCount; ++i) {
        output << delimiter << static_cast<uint16_t>(ip.parts_[i]);
    }

    return output;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, Ip &ip)
{
    uint16_t t;
    input >> std::noskipws;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < partsCount; ++i) {
        [[likely]] if ((input >> t) && t <= std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()) {
            ip.parts_[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>(t);
        } else {
            [[unlikely]] if (!input.eof()) {
                input.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);
            }
            return input;
        }
        if (i != partsCount - 1) {
            [[likely]] if (input.peek() == delimiter) {
                input.ignore();
            } else {
                input.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);
                return input;
            }
        }
    }

    return input;
}

std::pair<std::vector<ip::Ip>, bool> readIps(std::istream &stream)
{
    static constexpr auto                noLimit = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max();
    std::pair<std::vector<ip::Ip>, bool> result;
    ip::Ip                               ip;
    try {
        while (stream >> ip) {
            result.first.push_back(std::move(ip));
            stream.ignore(noLimit, '\n');
        }
    } catch (...){
        result.second = false;
        return result;
    }
    result.second = !stream.bad();

    return result;
}

} // namespace ip

CMakeLists.txt:
add_library(ip STATIC
   src/ip.cpp
   include/ip_lib/ip.h
)

target_include_directories(ip
    PUBLIC include
    PRIVATE src include/ip_lib)

set_target_properties(ip PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
target_compile_features(ip PUBLIC cxx_std_20)

Contents - tests:
ip_stream_operators_test.cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "ip_lib/ip.h"

TEST(IpTest, ValidReadOperatorTest)
{
    std::stringstream s {};
    ip::Ip            ip;

    auto isCorrectReadIp = [&s, &ip](std::string ipStr, uint8_t p1, uint8_t p2, uint8_t p3, uint8_t p4) {
        s.clear();
        s.str(std::move(ipStr));
        s >> ip;
        return ip.is(p1, p2, p3, p4);
    };

    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("0.0.0.0", 0, 0, 0, 0));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("1.1.1.1", 1, 1, 1, 1));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("1.1.1.1\n", 1, 1, 1, 1));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("1.1.1.1\n1", 1, 1, 1, 1));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("1.1.1.1\na", 1, 1, 1, 1));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("1.1.1.1\n2.2.2.2", 1, 1, 1, 1));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("1.1.1.1\n ", 1, 1, 1, 1));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("1.1.1.1\n 1", 1, 1, 1, 1));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("1.1.1.1\n 2.2.2.2", 1, 1, 1, 1));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("255.255.255.255", 255, 255, 255, 255));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("255.0.1.255", 255, 0, 1, 255));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("0.255.255.0", 0, 255, 255, 0));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("1.255.255.1 ", 1, 255, 255, 1));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("1.2.2.1 2", 1, 2, 2, 1));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isCorrectReadIp("1.2.2.255a", 1, 2, 2, 255));
}

TEST(IpTest, InvalidReadOperatorTest)
{
    std::stringstream s {};
    ip::Ip            ip;

    auto readFailed = [&s, &ip](std::string ipStr) {
        s.clear();
        s.str(std::move(ipStr));
        s >> ip;
        return s.fail() || s.bad();
    };

    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed(""));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("255."));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("255.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("255.255.255"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("255.255.255."));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1. 1.1.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1.\n1.1.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1.1 . 1.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1.1.1. 1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("255.255.255.\n1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1\n1.1.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1\n2.3.4.5"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("0..0.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1...0"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("256.0.0.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1.333.333.333"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("a.1.1.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1.a.1.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("0.0.aa.12"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("0.0.12.b"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed(".1.1.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed(".0.0."));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1.1,1.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1-1.1.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("1.1.1:1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("65535.1.1.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(readFailed("0.65536.1.1"));
}

TEST(IpTest, WriteOperatorTest)
{
    auto isIpWrittenCorrectly = [](ip::Ip ip, std::string expected){
        std::stringstream ss {};
        ss << ip;
        return ss.str() == expected;
    };

    EXPECT_TRUE(isIpWrittenCorrectly({0, 0, 0, 0}, "0.0.0.0"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isIpWrittenCorrectly({ 1, 1, 1, 1 }, "1.1.1.1"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(isIpWrittenCorrectly({ 255, 255, 255, 255 }, "255.255.255.255"));
}

test_ip_reading.cpp:
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "ip_lib/ip.h"

TEST(IpTest, ValidReadIpsTest)
{
    auto check = [](std::vector<std::array<int, 4>> input) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        for (const auto& ip : input) {
            ss << ip[0] << '.' << ip[1] << '.' << ip[2] << '.' << ip[3] << '\n';
        }
        auto [ips, success] = ip::readIps(ss);

        ASSERT_TRUE(success);
        ASSERT_EQ(ips.size(), input.size());
    };

    check({});
    check({ {} });
    check({ { 1, 1, 1, 1 } });
    check({ { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 } });
    check({ { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 254, 255 }, { 255, 0, 0, 1 }, { 0, 255, 0, 255 } });
}

TEST(IpTest, InvalidReadIpsTest)
{
    auto check = [](std::string input, int errorCaseNumber = 0) {
        std::stringstream ss { input };
        auto [ips, success] = ip::readIps(ss);
        ASSERT_FALSE(success);
    };

    check({ { "1" } });
    check({ { "1\n1.1.1.1" } });
    check({ { "1.1.1.1\n1.1.1.\n1.1.1.1" } });
    check({ { "1.1.1.1\n1.1.1.2\n\n\n3333" } });
    check({ { "1.1.1.1\n1.1.1.2\n\n\na.2.3.4" } });
    check({ { "1.1.q.1\n1.1.1.2\n\n\n1.2.3.4" } });
    check({ { "1.1.1.1111\n1.1.1.2\n\n\n1.2.3.4" } });
}

CMakeLists.txt:
include(FetchContent)
if (POLICY CMP0135)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0135 NEW)
endif()
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/refs/tags/v1.14.0.zip
)
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

include(GoogleTest)

add_executable(UnitTests 
    ip_stream_operators_test.cpp
    test_ip_reading.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(UnitTests PUBLIC GTest::gtest_main ip)

gtest_discover_tests(UnitTests)


I don’t deal with CMake, so I’m not going to comment on any of the CMake stuff.
I’m also not really a fan of GoogleTest, so I don’t know much about what specific functionality it has. I’ll make general comments about the test code, but I can’t suggest how to actually do the things I’ll suggest in GoogleTest.
So, let’s start with main.cpp. There’s not really much to say here except:

Never use std::endl. '\n' or "\n" is always better.
There is no need to return 0; in main().

So let’s move on to ip_lib/ip.h:
#pragma once

Don’t use #pragma once. It is not standard, for a very good reason.
Use include guards. If you are worried about clashes, append a string of random characters or generate a UUID or something.
#include <iosfwd>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <cinttypes>

When dealing with header files, it always wise to sort them logically. Normally that means grouping them by library, then sorting them alphabetically.
constexpr inline size_t partsCount = 4;
constexpr inline char   delimiter  = '.';

These should really be localized in the Ip class. They are not general constants. partsCount means nothing outside of an IP address, and delimiter will be different for IPv4 vs IPv6 (not to mention anything else that might have a delimiter).
Also, and this is a general problem throughout your code, it is not size_t, it is std::size_t. The naked form “works” for historical reasons, but that will break when you modernize your code by moving to modules. It needs to be std::size_t, and you need to include the correct header.
This is true for std::size_t, std::uint8_t, and std::uint16_t.
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &input, const Ip &ip);

So, first, as a matter of style, in C++, we keep the type information together.
In other words:

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &input, const Ip &ip): this is C-style.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& input, const Ip& ip): this is C++-style.

Now it is good practice to make the stream inserter a friend of the class, but usually that means using the “hidden friend” pattern. For that to work, the stream inserter has to be defined in the class, not just declared.
That is usually not a problem, because the stream inserter can usually be a template… and should be.
First let’s see what’s wrong with the current stream inserter. Try this:
std::cout
    << std::setw(20)
    << std::setfill('_')
    << std::left
    << ip::Ip{1,2,3,4}
;

With this code, I would expect:
1.2.3.4_____________

But what I get is:
1___________________.2.3.4

If we look at the implementation of the inserter, we can see why this happens:
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const ip::Ip &ip)
{
    output << static_cast<uint16_t>(ip.parts_[0]);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < partsCount; ++i) {
        output << delimiter << static_cast<uint16_t>(ip.parts_[i]);
    }

    return output;
}

For illustration and for toy examples, writing an IOstreams inserter as just a series of << works well enough, but that just isn’t the way to write any non-trivial, real-world inserter.
There is a standard pattern for writing inserters, and it is this:
class Ip
{
public:
    template <typename Char, typename Traits>
    friend auto operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& o, Ip const& v) -> std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&
    {
        if (o)
        {
            auto oss = std::ostringstream{};
            // setup oss as necessary

            // write to oss however you want

            auto const s = std::move(oss).str();
            o << s.c_str();
        }

        return o;
    }

    // ...
};

All you need to do is fill in those two comments with the stuff relevant to your type.
The first part is the setup. Now, generally, there are two types of setup: locale-aware, and non-locale-aware. For locale-aware, you usually want to copy the local from the actual output stream, so your setup is: oss.imbue(o.getloc()). But I don’t think you want the output of IPs to be locale-sensitive. So you want the non-locale-aware setup, which is: oss.imbue(std::locale::classic()).
(If there are any relevant formatting flags, you may want to copy them with copyfmt(), but I’m assuming there are none in this case.)
And once the temporary stream is set up, now you just output as you please:
class Ip
{
public:
    template <typename Char, typename Traits>
    friend auto operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& o, Ip const& v) -> std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&
    {
        if (o)
        {
            auto oss = std::ostringstream{};
            oss.imbue(std::locale::classic());

            oss << static_cast<uint16_t>(v.parts_[0]);
            for (size_t i = 1; i < partsCount; ++i) {
                oss << delimiter << static_cast<uint16_t>(v.parts_[i]);
            }

            auto const s = std::move(oss).str();
            o << s.c_str();
        }

        return o;
    }

    // ...
};

Now the output from the test case above not only returns the expected result, as a free bonus you can now stream to any type of stream: wide character, Unicode, whatever.
There’s still some work to be done on the actual output stuff, though.
For starters, there’s this: output << static_cast<uint16_t>(ip.parts_[0]);. Now, I know why you’re doing that static cast; if you don’t, it is printing a character. But this is the wrong way to fix that problem. The correct way is simple: output << +ip.parts_[0];. Yes. Literally. Just unary operator+. It works, perfectly, and is the correct way to handle this situation.
So the fixed code should be more like:
class Ip
{
public:
    template <typename Char, typename Traits>
    friend auto operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& o, Ip const& v) -> std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&
    {
        if (o)
        {
            auto oss = std::ostringstream{};
            oss.imbue(std::locale::classic());

            oss << +v.parts_[0];
            for (auto i = 1uz; i < partsCount; ++i)
                oss << delimiter << +v.parts_[i];

            auto const s = std::move(oss).str();
            o << s.c_str();
        }

        return o;
    }

    // ...
};

But honestly, while this is correct, it is wildly inefficient. You don’t need 90% of the power of IOstreams for this task. You are literally just converting 4 8-bit values to decimal numbers, with periods in between. You can do this without any mucking about with IOstreams, or even without any allocations at all:
class Ip
{
public:
    template <typename Char, typename Traits>
    friend auto operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& o, Ip const& v) -> std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&
    {
        if (o)
        {
            // Set up a buffer big enough for 15 chars and NUL.
            // IPv4 addresses never get longer than 15 chars
            // (yanno, assuming no ports or other stuff).
            auto buffer = std::array<char, 16>{};
            auto p = buffer.data();
            auto const q = buffer.data() + (buffer.size() - 1);

            std::ranges::for_each(v.parts_, [&buffer, &p, q, delimiter](auto part)
            {
                if (p != buffer.data())
                    *p++ = delimiter;

                p = std::to_chars(p, q, part).ptr;
            });

            o << buffer.data();
        }

        return o;
    }

    // ...
};

That conversion should probably be pulled out into its own function, because it can also be used to create a super-efficient to_string() function, among other things.
On to the extractor.
So, there are basically two ways to write an IOstreams extractor. One way is to use the istream interface, and the other is to use the streambuf interface.
Using the istream interface, you would basically write something like:
auto operator>>(std::istream& in, Ip& v) -> std::istream&
{
    auto first_part = true;
    for(auto&& part : v.parts_)
    {
        if (not std::exchange(first_part, false))
        {
            auto c = char{};
            if ((not (in >> c)) or (not std::istream::traits_type::eq(c, '.')))
                // fail
        }

        if (not (in >> part))
            // fail
    });

    return in;
}

This is very simplified because, again, you need to account for all the stream formatting options.
Using the streambuf interface, you would first construct the sentry and check it, then work with the stream buffer directly. It is much more complex… but also much more efficient.
Your actual code is sorta half-and-half. I would recommend going all-in on the streambuf method (in fact, I believe that the istream method is almost always more headache than it is worth).
What you would do is basically (this is completely untested code of course):
template <typename Char, typename Traits>
friend auto operator>>(std::basic_istream<Char, Traits>& in, Ip& v)
    -> std::basic_istream<Char, Traits>&
{
    if (auto const cerberus = typename std::basic_istream<Char, Traits>::sentry{in}; cerberus)
    {
        auto parts = std::array<int, 4>{};
        auto sb = in.rdbuf();

        auto&& ctype = std::use_facet<std::ctype<Char>>(in.getloc());

        auto const get_digit = [&ctype](auto sb)
        {
            using namespace std::string_view_literals;
            constexpr auto digits = "0123456789"sv;

            if (auto const ci = sb->sgetc(); not Traits::eq_int_type(ci, Traits::eof()))
            {
                if (auto const c = ctype.narrow(Traits::to_char_type(ci), char{}); c != char{})
                {
                    if (auto const p = std::ranges::find(digits, c); p != std::ranges::end(digits))
                    {
                        sb->sbumpc();
                        return int(std::ranges::distance(std::ranges::begin(digits), p));
                    }
                }
            }

            return -1;
        };

        for (auto i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
        {
            // First digit (required)
            if (auto const d = get_digit(sb); d > 0)
            {
                parts[i] = d;
            }
            else
            {
                in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
                return in;
            }

            // Additional 2 digits (optional)
            for (auto j = 0; j != 2; ++j)
            {
                if (auto const d = get_digit(sb); d > 0)
                    parts[i] = (parts[i] * 10) + d;
                else
                    break;
            }

            // Check value
            if (parts[i] > 255)
            {
                in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
                return in;
            }

            // Check for delimiter (if not last part)
            if (i != 3)
            {
                auto found_delimiter = false;
                if (auto const ci = sb->sgetc(); not Traits::eq_int_type(ci, Traits::eof()))
                    if (auto const c = ctype.narrow(Traits::to_char_type(ci), char{}); c == delimiter)
                        found_delimiter = true;

                if (found_delimiter)
                {
                    sb->sbumpc();
                }
                else
                {
                    in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
                    return in;
                }
            }
        }

        // If we got here, parsing was successful
        // so now we can modify the output value
        std::ranges::transform(parts, std::ranges::begin(v.parts_), [](auto part) { return static_cast<std::uint8_t>(part); });
    }

    return in;
}

Yes, that is quite a bit, but input and parsing is always a lot more work than output. It’s more complicated… but since most of it is just comparing characters and adjusting pointers (assuming no dives into underflow()), it will be much more efficient.
So let’s take a closer look at your current extractor:
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, Ip &ip)
{
    uint16_t t;
    input >> std::noskipws;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < partsCount; ++i) {
        [[likely]] if ((input >> t) && t <= std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()) {
            ip.parts_[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>(t);
        } else {
            [[unlikely]] if (!input.eof()) {
                input.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);
            }
            return input;
        }
        if (i != partsCount - 1) {
            [[likely]] if (input.peek() == delimiter) {
                input.ignore();
            } else {
                input.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);
                return input;
            }
        }
    }

    return input;
}

The first thing that strikes me as a problem is the input >> std::noskipws. If you’re going to do this, you need to be more careful.
First, you should ignore all the whitespace before you start parsing. That is what people expect of inserters. This is why you can read 3 integers with in >> i1 >> i2 >> i3;. In the very rare case where someone wants to not skip the whitespace, they can manually set that up by using std::noskipws. By doing that yourself, you are taking that option away from them. If you must disable whitespace skipping within your extractor, then you should make sure to first honour whatever the current stream setting is.
Second, if you do change the stream state, that could screw up reads that come after your extractor. Imagine I want to read an IP address, a port, and a path, and it’s formatted like 1.2.3.4  567  path/to/whatever. I write the natural code to read this as in >> ip >> port >> path;. Except… it doesn’t work, because after the IP address is read, the stream has been changed, and will no longer ignore whitespace, breaking everything else. As a general rule, you should never change the input stream in an extractor. (This is why working with the stream buffer is so attractive.) Or, if you do, you should be very careful to put things back the way you found them. For this you would need a RAII type, like those in Boost.IO.
The second thing that strikes me as a problem is your use of std::ios_base::badbit. That is not correct. badbit means the stream is broken; it could mean that a drive was disconnected while reading a file stream, or a network stream got disconnected, or whatever. You should never be setting badbit in an extractor; it is the stream that determines when it is broken, not the person reading from the stream. When the stream is “bad”, you can’t get any more data out of it. If you are getting data out of it, then the stream is not bad. If you are getting data, but not the data you want, then that is a “fail” condition. That means you should be using failbit.
Third… using uint16_t here is weird. Why not just unsigned?
And fourth… you are using [[likely]] and [[unlikely]] incorrectly. Using them at all in this context is silly. You are doing input parsing… this is not hot code. Even if the compiler optimizes these branches, there is effectively zero chance you will ever notice the difference. Any optimization gains on the level of branch prediction will be massively dwarfed by the I/O costs, not to mention the parsing. These attributes are just pointless noise. (And, again, they’re wrong, too.)
Finally I want to focus on this bit:
        [[likely]] if ((input >> t) && t <= std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()) {
            ip.parts_[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>(t);
        } else {
            [[unlikely]] if (!input.eof()) {
                input.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);
            }
            return input;
        }

I don’t even know why you are bothering to check for EOF. It really doesn’t make any sense.
If the input failed, you can just return immediately. Cramming that together with the limits check makes the logic harder to understand in my opinion; they are two different kinds of failures. One is “could not read a number”, the other is “number too large”. But okay, if you really do what to combine the checks, then the block should be:
        if ((input >> t) && (t <= std::numeric_limits<std::uint8_t>::max()))
        {
            ip.parts_[i] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(t);
        }
        else
        {
            input.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); // may throw
            return input;
        }

Moving on.
    Ip() = default;

Later you have a constexpr member function… but you don’t have a single constexpr constructor… so the constexpr function can never be constexpr. Except it could, because there is no reason this (and the other) constructor can’t be constexpr. And since it can never fail…:
    constexpr Ip() noexcept = default;

The same is true for the second constructor, but in that case, it should also be defined inline. There’s just no sense whatsoever defining it separately in the implementation file.
    constexpr uint8_t       &operator[](size_t i) { return parts_[i]; }
    constexpr const uint8_t &operator[](size_t i) const { return parts_[i]; }

Just FYI, you have a lurking bug here, though it is a very, very common one. Consider if I do: auto i = ip::Ip{}; auto& o = std::move(i)[0];. Now I’m holding a reference to a data member of a moved-from object.
To prevent this you would have to do:
    constexpr auto operator[](std::size_t i) &       -> std::uint8_t&       { return parts_[i]; }
    constexpr auto operator[](std::size_t i) const&  -> std::uint8_t const& { return parts_[i]; }
    constexpr auto operator[](std::size_t i) &&      -> std::uint8_t        { return parts_[i]; }
    constexpr auto operator[](std::size_t i) const&& -> std::uint8_t        { return parts_[i]; }

I would also not return a reference in the const& case, because what’s the point? A reference is way more expensive than just returning the octet value.
But these problems exist all over the place—even in the standard library—so it’s up to you whether to worry about them or not.
    bool           operator==(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ == rhs.parts_; }
    bool           operator!=(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ != rhs.parts_; }
    bool           operator<(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ < rhs.parts_; }
    bool           operator<=(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ <= rhs.parts_; }
    bool           operator>(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ > rhs.parts_; }
    bool           operator>=(const Ip &rhs) const { return parts_ >= rhs.parts_; }

All of these are just:
    constexpr auto operator<=>(Ip const&) const noexcept = default;

And you get three-way comparison support for free.
    constexpr bool is(uint8_t p1, uint8_t p2, uint8_t p3, uint8_t p4) const { 

This function cannot conceivably fail, and so should be noexcept.
std::pair<std::vector<ip::Ip>, bool> readIps(std::istream& stream);

Using std::pair like this is a bad idea. There is no protection whatsoever against simply ignoring the bool and just using the vector, good or bad.
There is a proper type for this: std::expected. To use std::expected, you need a proper “unexpected” type. For something like this, that would probably be an enum of parsing errors… but for that to be useful, you probably don’t want to use operator>>, but rather a proper parse function that returns std::expected<Ip, Ip::parse_error> instead. (And that parsing error enum should probably be std::is_error_condition_enum, and there should be an error category, etc..)
And if you can’t use std::expected for whatever reason, you should make something similar. It can hold a std::pair<std::vector<ip::Ip>, bool> internally, but you should not just use a naked pair or tuple.
std::pair<std::vector<ip::Ip>, bool> readIps(std::istream &stream)
{
    static constexpr auto                noLimit = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max();
    std::pair<std::vector<ip::Ip>, bool> result;
    ip::Ip                               ip;
    try {
        while (stream >> ip) {
            result.first.push_back(std::move(ip));
            stream.ignore(noLimit, '\n');
        }
    } catch (...){
        result.second = false;
        return result;
    }
    result.second = !stream.bad();

    return result;
}

So, once again, you are using the stream’s “bad” flag. That is wrong. You should be using the “fail” flag.
Most of the complexity of this function is due to the fact that the extractor was not written idiomatically. If the extractor were written the way most stream extractors are, then this function would just be:
auto readIps(std::istream& stream)
    -> std::expected<std::vector<Ip>, std::exception_ptr>
{
    try
    {
        auto ips = std::vector{
            std::istream_iterator<Ip>{stream},
            std::istream_iterator<Ip>{}
        };

        return ips;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return std::unexpected{std::current_exception()};
    }
}

Of course, this won’t diagnose most parse errors, but that’s because IOstreams just really kinda sucks for that kind of detailed error analysis. When you are reading an unknown number of “things” from a stream, you expect it to fail on the last one. There is no way to tell whether it failed from reaching the end of the stream or if there was some unexpected garbage.
auto readIps(std::istream& stream)
    -> std::expected<std::vector<Ip>, std::exception_ptr>
{
    try
    {
        auto ips = std::vector<Ip>{};

        auto ip = Ip{};
        while (stream >> ip)
            ips.push_back(ip);

        // Here, if all went well, we expect that:
        //   stream.fail() == true
        //   stream.eof()  == true
        //   stream.bad()  == false

        // If stream.bad() is true, then the stream is just
        // hopelessly broken.

        // If stream.eof() is *NOT* true, then we are 100% sure
        // there was a parse error.

        // *HOWEVER*... if stream.eof() is true, then
        // stream.fail() *MUST* be true. We know we hit the end
        // of the stream... but we *DON'T* know if there was
        // anything there that was partially parsed as an IP.
        // There is just no way to tell at this point.

        // It is theoretically possible to tell by checking
        // *BEFORE* the attempted read... but... it's just
        // not worth it. If you want this kind of deep parse
        // fail diagnostic, don't use operator>>, use a proper
        // parse function.

        return ips;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return std::unexpected{std::current_exception()};
    }
}

If you actually want to diagnose parse errors, then you need a dedicated parsing function like:
class Ip
{
public:
    enum class parse_error
    {
        ...
    };

    static constexpr auto parse_from(std::istream&)
        -> std::expected<Ip, parse_error>;

    // ...
};


auto readIps(std::istream& stream)
    -> std::expected<std::vector<Ip>, Ip::parse_error>
{
    try
    {
        auto ips = std::vector<Ip>{};

        while (stream)
        {
            if (auto res = Ip::parse_from(stream); res)
                ips.push_back(std::move(res).value());
            else
                return std::unexpected{std::move(res).error()};
        }

        return ips;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return std::unexpected{Ip::parse_error::whatevs};
    }
}

Now if you really, really want to do line-oriented reading of IPs, then you should use std::getline(), and parse separately. Like so:
class Ip
{
public:
    enum class parse_error
    {
        ...
    };

    static constexpr auto parse(std::string_view)
        -> std::expected<Ip, parse_error>;

    // ...
};


auto readIps(std::istream& stream)
    -> std::expected<std::vector<Ip>, Ip::parse_error>
{
    try
    {
        auto ips = std::vector<Ip>{};

        auto line = std::string{};
        while (std::getline(stream, line))
        {
            if (auto res = Ip::parse(line); res)
                ips.push_back(std::move(res).value());
            else
                return std::unexpected{std::move(res).error()};
        }

        return ips;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return std::unexpected{Ip::parse_error::whatevs};
    }
}

The parse function could detect leading or trailing garbage, and return the appropriate error code.
Finally the tests. The tests are quite well-written, though they cover very little. For example, there is no test to ensure that Ip{} initializes an all-zero IP (assuming that is the intention) or that Ip{1, 2, 3, 4} initializes to 1.2.3.4 and not 2.1.4.3 or something else.
There are two problems with your tests.

They are way too complex.
They are not isolated.

Tests should be simple… like stupidly simple. Any test more than 3–5 lines is probably too complex. Any test that includes any kind of loop or conditional is definitely too complex.
A test should be, ideally, 2 or 3 lines:

Setup (ideally, there should be none, but this is usually not possible).
Action (the thing you are actually testing).
Assertion(s).

When tests are not isolated from each other, borked code in one test can fuck up every other test. .clear() is not a magic bullet; there are plenty of ways to muck up a string stream that .clear() won’t fix.
There is a better way. (At least, there is a better way in every mature testing library I’ve ever used, so I have to assume GoogleTest can do it, too.) Any non-toy testing library should support parameterized tests. The idea is you just set up a big-ass collection of test data and expected values, and then run a test on all of them. That is close to what you have done, but, as I said, there is a better way.
GoogleTest must be able to do this, but I don’t know what its syntax for it is. So I’ll just guess.
constexpr auto ip_values = std::to_array<
    std::tuple<
        std::array<std::uint8_t, 4>,    // octets
        std::string_view                // string representation
    >
>({
    {{0,   0,   0,   0},   "0.0.0.0"},
    {{255, 255, 255, 255}, "255.255.255.255"},
    {{1,   2,   3,   4},   "1.2.3.4"},
    // and more if you want
});

TEST_WITH_DATA(Ip, ConstructionWithOctets,
    ip_values,              // data set to use
    octets,                 // first data parameter
    [[maybe_unused]] string // second data parameter (not used here)
)
{
    // Setup.
    // none

    // Action.
    auto const ip = Ip{octets[0], octets[1], octets[2], octets[3]};

    // Assertion(s).
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[0], octets[0]);
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[1], octets[1]);
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[2], octets[2]);
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[3], octets[3]);
    // The above is ugly, but I'm sure there is a way to make
    // a predicate test, so you could just do:
    //   EXPECT_WHATEVS(ip_has_octets, ip, octets);
}

TEST_WITH_DATA(Ip, StreamInsert,
    ip_values,  // data set to use
    octets,     // first data parameter
    string      // second data parameter
)
{
    // Setup.
    auto oss = std::ostringstream{};
    auto const ip = Ip{octets[0], octets[1], octets[2], octets[3]};

    // Action.
    oss << ip;

    // Assertion(s).
    EXPECT_TRUE(oss.good());
    EXPECT_EQ(oss.str(), string);
}

TEST_WITH_DATA(Ip, StreamExtract_StreamStateIsGood,
    ip_values,  // data set to use
    octets,     // first data parameter
    string      // second data parameter
)
{
    // Setup.
    auto iss = std::istringstream{string};

    // Action.
    auto ip = Ip{};
    iss >> ip;

    // Assertion(s).
    EXPECT_TRUE(bool(iss));
}

TEST_WITH_DATA(Ip, StreamExtract_DataReadCorrectly,
    ip_values,  // data set to use
    octets,     // first data parameter
    string      // second data parameter
)
{
    // Setup.
    auto iss = std::istringstream{string};

    // Action.
    auto ip = Ip{};
    iss >> ip;

    // Assertion(s).
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[0], octets[0]);
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[1], octets[1]);
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[2], octets[2]);
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[3], octets[3]);
}

// and for more complex tests, more complex data:

constexpr auto valid_input_data = std::to_array<
    std::tuple<
        std::string_view,               // input data
        std::array<std::uint8_t, 4>,    // octets
        std::string_view                // leftover data
    >
>({
    {" 0.0.0.0", {0, 0, 0, 0}, {}},
    {"\t1.2.3.4", {1, 2, 3, 4}, {}},
    {"\r \n \t \v 5.6.7.8", {5, 6, 7, 8}, {}},
    {"127.0.0.1x", {127, 0, 0, 1}, "x"},
    {"7.8.9.1234", {7, 8, 9, 123}, "4"},
    // and so on
});

TEST_WITH_DATA(Ip, ComplexStreamExtract_StreamStateIsGood,
    valid_input_data,   // data set to use
    input,              // first data parameter
    octets,             // second data parameter
    leftover            // third data parameter
)
{
    // Setup.
    auto iss = std::istringstream{input};

    // Action.
    auto ip = Ip{};
    iss >> ip;

    // Assertion(s).
    EXPECT_TRUE(bool(iss));
}

TEST_WITH_DATA(Ip, ComplexStreamExtract_DataReadCorrectly,
    valid_input_data,   // data set to use
    input,              // first data parameter
    octets,             // second data parameter
    leftover            // third data parameter
)
{
    // Setup.
    auto iss = std::istringstream{input};

    // Action.
    auto ip = Ip{};
    iss >> ip;

    // Assertion(s).
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[0], octets[0]);
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[1], octets[1]);
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[2], octets[2]);
    EXPECT_EQ(ip[3], octets[3]);
}

TEST_WITH_DATA(Ip, ComplexStreamExtract_LeftoverDataIsGood,
    valid_input_data,   // data set to use
    input,              // first data parameter
    octets,             // second data parameter
    leftover            // third data parameter
)
{
    // Setup.
    auto iss = std::istringstream{input};

    // Action.
    auto ip = Ip{};
    iss >> ip;
    auto const string = std::string{
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{iss},
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}
    };

    // Assertion(s).
    EXPECT_EQ(string, leftover);
}

constexpr auto invalid_input_data = std::to_array<std::string_view>({
    {},
    "1",
    "1.2.3.",
    "1.256.3.4",
    // and so on
});

TEST_WITH_DATA(Ip, ComplexStreamExtract_InvalidData_StreamStateIsNotGood,
    invalid_input_data, // data set to use
    input               // first data parameter
)
{
    // Setup.
    auto iss = std::istringstream{input};

    // Action.
    auto ip = Ip{};
    iss >> ip;

    // Assertion(s).
    EXPECT_FALSE(bool(iss));
}

// and so on...

Doing it this way allows you to trivially add new test cases without touching any existing test cases. And breaking up the tests into finer checks makes it much easier to narrow down:

exactly what is going wrong; and
exactly what data is causing it to.

I hope that’s enough to help you with the GoogleTest stuff.

Ooh) Thank you very much. Now I need some time to work out all of this.
